# Dropwizard @QueryParam returns null rather than reading the parameter

Tags: java, json, url, jackson, dropwizard

I have an application that takes a `@QueryParam` value as follows:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*

//Some stuff here

@POST
@Path("/mypath")
public Response generate(
   @QueryParam("value") String value) {
  // value is always null here. 
}
```

When I call this method through the following URL value is `null`:

```
http://myhost/mypath?value=somevalue
```

Answer (score -1):

While the import javax.ws.rs.* does not cause the compiler to complain, javax.ws.rs.QueryParm import does not happen.  As such, change the imports to this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
```

Then the value comes in.

Comment: Changing from wildcard to specific imports would have no impact... If that were the case the JVM would simply be broken since inception

Comment: Alex,  I agree and maybe there's something else wrong in my maven dependencies.  However, when I do import javax.ws.rs.* I don't import QueryParam (though I do import everything else) and when I specifically import QueryParam I get QueryParam...though both compile, one does not work.  Please suggest what other information I could provide:  Compiler Version, DropWizard Version, Maven Version, Maven Dependencies?